# WPF MVVM DataGrid/Map

Tags: wpf, mvvm, bing-maps

Ok, so I am working on an asset tracking application that is built using wpf. The dashboard view will have a DataGrid with rows of data and a map that corresponds with the grid. I currently have it working, but I feel it's more of a hack - and that with wpf I should be able to make the two items update simultaneously.

Currently what I do is get the data from a web service, format it into record objects and then bind to the DataGrid. I also take that same datasource and create my map icons, location, etc... using a DataTemplate. It all works. What I don't like is that when data is filtered in the grid - I have to manually loop through the map data and filter it - to match the grid.The grid already contains the data that I need (latitude/longitude, Location) to create my map points. I just can't seem to get the two items (Grid/Map) to bind to the same source.

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML, or maybe a small repro project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection` for your data source but don't bind to that because that will bind to the default view of your collection, bind both controls to `ICollectionView` that you control so as you change your collection view in code both controls will update without the need to write any code to sync them...

So in your case, when you filter the data, your view that is using TwoWay binding will change and since the map is bound to same view the changes in view will be immediately visible in the map as well...